# Get Data from a Web Page, then Display It On Another Web Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I want to get data from an HTML web page, then display it in a Div on another HTML web page, with jQuery.

I tried jQuery's get(), load(), and ajax() methods, but unable to get the data. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/YcprC/

- What's wrong with my code?
- Is it possible to get data from an ASP.NET web page, then display it on an HTML web page?
- How to get data from a Div in a web page, then display it in another Div on another web page?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not get data from other websites because of what is know as Same Origin Policy:

> In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept
>   for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as
>   JavaScript. **The policy permits scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with
>   no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and
>   properties across pages on different sites**.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

To workaround that, you should implement [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Learn more about it [here](http://www.json-p.org/).

Or you may also use Yahoo's YQL, see:

- [Quick Tip: Cross Domain AJAX Request with YQL and jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/)

Comment: I found this jQuery plugin (using YQL): http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/  But it can only get the entire web page content, not get the data from a particular Div on a web page.

Comment: @Bayu: Yes you can use that too, it works fine. I had used it too :)

Comment: YQL is interesting and may well offer a way ahead but please note that (if I understand correctly) it relies on a 3rd-party (!Yahoo) proxy server that is not under your control. What if !Yahoo withdrew the service or introduced a revenue scheme and you chose not to pay?

Comment: Yes it's better to use our own PHP proxy file. I've tried it, but the result is the same as YQL, it doesn't return all contents.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because of crossdomain security policies. I recommend you load the webpages data with PHP (easy way is [file_get_contents](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), pro way is [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)) and load that php with your jquery.

Comment: I can't use PHP, because I want to create a mobile app page with jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap.

Comment: If the page being scraped is small enough then you can use the Yahoo Pipes service to fetch the information and pass it back to the app as a JSON string. For anything bigger or more complicated use the Google App Engine or run the php fetching of data through a free web Host.

Comment: Thanks Skizz, I'll try it later. I found this great jQuery plugin: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/  But it can only get the entire web page content, not get the data from a particular Div on a web page.

Answer (score 2):

Same domain - simple. 
Cross-domain - difficult. Not natively supported except in old versions of IE (5.5 and 6)

Comment: The web pages are in different domains. Is it possible to do it in Chrome?

Comment: Straightforwardly no. Options are: (1) JSONP but limited to 3rd-party servers that serve data in JSONP format; (2) Flash solutions, in particular Flensed; (3) Google Caja, though I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

If the page being scraped is small enough then you can use the Yahoo Pipes service to fetch the information and pass it back to the app as a JSON string. For anything bigger or more complicated use the Google App Engine or run the php fetching of data through a free web Host.

Comment: Thanks Skizz, I'll try it later. I found this great jQuery plugin: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/  But it can only get the entire web page content, not get the data from a particular Div on a web page.